# Two ways of implementing a linked list: which is better?

Tags: c, linked-list

I know generally two ways to design a generic linked list datastructure in C. And I'm wondering which is better. Before asking the question, I'll introduce both methods shortly:

One method is to build functions around a structure like the following:

```
struct list_element {
    struct list_element *prev;
    struct list_element *next;
    void *data;
};
```

Obviously, the data pointer points to the payload. The list element struct is outside the payload. This is e.g. how glib has designed its double linked list facility: http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.26/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html

Another method is the way how it's done in the Linux kernel: http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/. There is no void pointer to the payload in the list element struct. Instead the list element struct is included in the payload struct:

```
struct list_element {
    struct list_element *prev;
    struct list_element *next;
};

struct person {
    char name[20];
    unsigned int age;
    struct list_element list_entry;
};
```

A special macro is used to get a pointer to the payload struct given a pointer to the list_entry, its name withing the payload struct and the type of the payload struct (the list_entry() macro).

Finally, **here is the question:** What is the advantage of the latter of the two methods of constructing a linked list? A few times I've heard people say the second is more 'generic' than the first, but why? I would even argue that the first method is more generic because the payload structures are list implementation agnostic, which isn't the case with the second method.
One more downside of the second method is if you want to place the payload in more than one list, you should a struct list_element member for each list in the payload structure.

Edit:
To summarize so far I saw two answers which were important for me:

- With the first method: removing a payload from the list involves looping through the complete list until the list element pointing to the payload is found. You don't need to do this with the second method. (Answer from Patrick)
- With the first method you have to do two malloc()s for each element: one for the payload and one for the list element struct. With the second method one malloc() is sufficient. (Answer from Roddy)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first approach might seem less intrusive but in many cases it isn't (unless you add additional data structures).

Imagine you have a list of thousand persons and you want to remove one of them from the list.  If the person doesn't know where it is in the list, you will have to scan the whole list first to get the exact place of the person.

You can solve this by adding a pointer from the person to its corresponding list structure, but this defeats the non-intrusiveness (does this word exist?) of the solution.

Another alternative is to have a hash map that maps the memory addresses of the persons to the memory addresses of the list nodes.  Then finding the node in the list is much faster (but still slower than the intrusive way).  However, since this will take a even more memory, I suggest not to do this.

Therefore, the easiest and simplest solution is the second one.

Answer (score 10):

It's horses for courses.

The first method is less efficient as it typically requires two `malloc()`s and `free()`s for each list element, and an additional pointer indirection to access them - and of course storage space for the pointer.

But, it allows different list elements to have different size payloads, which is potentially more awkward with the second approach.

For the second approach I would reorder the struct so the list element is at the start - this does then give some flexibility with different payload sizes.

```
struct person {
    struct list_element list_entry;
    unsigned int age;
    char name[20];  // now could be variable length.
};
```

Comment: excellent, you did suggest the re-order. I'll delete my partial answer with only that in it.

Comment: ... and with the reorder, observe that the first is pretty much a special case of the second, but the payload is a `void*` instead of an `unsigned int` and an array. Then the difference between the two is as much about the API you write, as it is about the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

The first is better because you can have list nodes with no data at all.

With the second option you always use the space (e.g. the 20 chars for the names) regardless of actual usage.

Comment: Why would you want items in your list which contain no data at all? Maybe I should note that in the first method all void pointers in a list always point to structs of the same type.

Comment: The second option makes no requirements that all nodes be of the same type. If you modify the requirements a bit so `struct list_element` is always the first member, then the `next` and `prev` methods are easy to generically implement, and can point to any kind of structure - which doesn't have to be the same kind of structure as the last node. (If you think this isn't type safe and is dangerous, it can't be less type-unsafe than a `void *`.)

Comment: @Bart You might have an algorithm that temporarily requires list nodes with no data. Maybe you are re-shuffling the data, changing their order.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is an intrusive list. You have to modify the structure you want to store in the list. You gain a little bit of performance with this approach because of less indirection. If you need a more flexible solution and not the last bit of performance, you should use the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

The second method is 'intrusive'; it requires a modification to the type that is put on the list.  The type on the list (or lists) has to know that it is on the list.  You have to be able to modify the structure to put it on the lists.

The first method is not intrusive.  It does not require modifications to the structure.  You can put any type on the list.  You could even have heterogeneous types on a single list, though that would be fraught with problems.  However, even if the base type is not modifiable by you, you can place it on the first type of list.  Against that, it requires more space.

So, if you have full control over the type of the data to be put on the list (and can modify it to support the lists you need), the second type has some advantages over the first.  In the context of the Linux kernel, the preconditions are met and it makes sense.  Otherwise, the first type is more flexible, but has slightly more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more of a conceptual/analysis issue. Is the entity you're working with something that has lists  or do you have a list of instances?

In other words, if what you're managing in the data has an independent existence, the first makes sense since whatever data points at will be manipulated independently. If the data is always and necessarily part of the list, then the second approach may be clearer.

As in most design decisions, the most important criteria should be which is clearer and most obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This, I think is a highly subjective question for no criteria is given against which to compare the two.

For simple lists, I tend to use a combination of the two.

```
struct list_node {
    struct list_node *  prev;
    struct list_node *  next;
};

struct some_struct {
    struct list_node  node;
    ...
};
```

Although this looks nearly identical to your second, note that the linked list node is the first element of "some_struct".  This means that when you advance to the next, or rewind to the previous node in the list, the pointer is at the start of the structure.  Otherwise I would be forced to perform some pointer math to get to the start of "some_struct".  As it currently is, I can simply cast.

However, such a method does have its limitations.  For example, if I wanted a structure with more than one linked list, each of the listed methods suffers from the flaw in that it requires pointer arithmetic to get to the start of at least one of the structures.  To get around this, some implementations (such as those in BSD VFS code) use macros to create the linked list elements.  In these, the linked list always points to the start of the structure, but the macro contains code to automatically apply the offset of the node within the structure if you desire it (for advancing to the next, or rewinding the previous).

Hope this helps.

Edit: Fixed some terminology.